# Using link-local address for crossover network connection

Tags: systemd, avahi

I would like to use link-local address to connect an embedded device (running systemd-networkd) to a PC (Ubuntu, Win, OS X) using a crossover cable (no switch or DHCP server).

When I connect over a network providing DHCP everything works fine, the `*.local` address is linked to the DHCP IP, and avahi browser is able to detect my device on the network.

I only tried a crossover connection to Ubuntu for now, if I use the GUI to change the network config from *Automatic (DHCP)* to *Link-Local Only* both my embedded device and PC get a LL IP and I am able to ping the device from my PC using the LL IP (obtained using `ip a` while connected over a serial interface), but I am unable to address it using the `*.local` name and `avahi-browser` is also not finding anything.

I could not find an example online discussing my use case, which is strange, since *zeroconf* is kind of intended for handling such use cases.

This are IP settings from my embedded device (Ubuntu 16.04.01 on ARMhf):

```
root@rp-f00321:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:26:32:f0:03:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.171.143/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::226:32ff:fef0:321/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

This are my wired network settings:

```
root@rp-f00321:~# cat /etc/systemd/network/wired.network 
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
DHCP=yes
IPForward=yes
IPMasquerade=yes
```

I also tried to add the next two options, but it did not help:

```
MulticastDNS=yes
IPv4LLRoute=yes
```

Avahi daemon status:

```
root@rp-f00321:~# systemctl status avahi-daemon -l -n 50
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service.d
           └─ad.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-10-26 10:16:04 UTC; 41min ago
 Main PID: 1552 (avahi-daemon)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.6.32-rc starting up."
   CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
           ├─1552 avahi-daemon: running [rp-f00321.local
           └─1553 avahi-daemon: chroot helpe

Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Process 1456 died: No such process; trying to remove PID file. (/var/run/avahi-daemon//pid)
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 107) and group 'avahi' (GID 110).
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: avahi-daemon 0.6.32-rc starting up.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Successfully called chroot().
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Loading service file /services/bazaar.service.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Loading service file /services/ssh.service.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::226:32ff:fef0:321.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 169.254.171.143.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Registering new address record for fe80::226:32ff:fef0:321 on eth0.*.
Oct 26 10:16:04 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Registering new address record for 169.254.171.143 on eth0.IPv4.
Oct 26 10:16:05 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Server startup complete. Host name is rp-f00321.local. Local service cookie is 1486970882.
Oct 26 10:16:06 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Service "rp-f00321 SSH" (/services/ssh.service) successfully established.
Oct 26 10:16:06 rp-f00321 avahi-daemon[1552]: Service "rp-f00321 HTTP" (/services/bazaar.service) successfully established.
```

I could ping my PC using the `.local` name, but it stopped working now:

```
# ping dent.local
PING dent.local (169.254.100.55) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from Dent.local (169.254.100.55): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.776 ms
64 bytes from Dent.local (169.254.100.55): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.634 ms
```

---

This are IP settings from my host PC (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:8e:8f:f5:a3:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enx00e04c534458: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:53:44:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.100.55/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link enx00e04c534458
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e07d:b734:e921:e87/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And this are my ping attempts:

```
$ ping 169.254.171.143
PING 169.254.171.143 (169.254.171.143) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 169.254.171.143: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.679 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.171.143: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.706 ms
^C
--- 169.254.171.143 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.679/0.692/0.706/0.029 ms
$ ping rp-f00321.local
ping: unknown host rp-f00321.local
```

Comment: There apparently *was* a bug that sounds like it might have been related [avahi incorrectly ignores mDNS response records containing link-local addresses](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=567067) but it looks like it should have been patched looong ago - maybe that gives you somewhere to start though?

Comment: does `grep '^hosts' /etc/nsswitch.conf` show `hosts: files mdns4_minimal ...`?